# Android: how to know when SD-card is un-mounted

Tags: android, notifications, sd-card

I am working on an application that reads media from the sd-card and plays it.. However, there are certain events when the sd-card is physically removed from the device or the device is attached to a computer and the sd-card is mounted on the computer.. Whenever the sd-card is removed, a notification is generated and can be seen in the notification bar. I want my application to respond to those notifications. For example, whenever the user physically removes the card or attaches it to the computer, I want my application to display a message like "sd card removed".. Is there any way to respond to these notifications??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want my application to respond to those notifications.

No, you don't. You want to respond to the broadcast `Intents` that are also used to create those `Notifications`.

Look at the [documentation for the `Intent` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), at the `ACTION_MEDIA_*` set of broadcast actions.

Comment: I think you are very much right.. Can you please elaborate a bit more.  I am quite a novice in android.. You help will be highly appreciated.. Thanks alot..

Answer (score 1):

I know question is old but I ended up here looking for this code, so here it is.

In the manifest.xml register the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="it.myapp.receiver.OnMediaMountedReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then create receiver class:

```
public class OnMediaMountedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = OnMediaMountedReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Media mounted!");
    if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Media path: " + intent.getDataString());
    }
    }
}
```